# My SmoothFollow Camera rotates around x axis(left-right) but not around y-axis(up-down)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my Smooth follow camera script. I'm using the EasyTouch asset. My script is attached to RCC_Camera object while RCC_camera script is disabled.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SmoothFollow : MonoBehaviour
{

    // The target we are following
    public Transform target;
    // The distance in the x-z plane to the target
    public float distance = 10.0f;
    // the height we want the camera to be above the target
    public float height = 5.0f;
    // How much we 
    public float heightDamping = 2.0f;
    public float rotationDamping = 3.0f;
    public float MyY;
    public float MyX;

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Early out if we don't have a target
        if (!target) return;

        // Calculate the current rotation angles
        float wantedRotationAngle = target.eulerAngles.y;
        float wantedHeight = target.position.y + height;

        float currentRotationAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        float currentHeight = transform.position.y;
        // Damp the rotation around the y-axis
        currentRotationAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle(currentRotationAngle, wantedRotationAngle, rotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);

        // Damp the height
        currentHeight = Mathf.Lerp(currentHeight, wantedHeight, heightDamping);
        Debug.Log("Height line");

        // Convert the angle into a rotation
        var currentRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, currentRotationAngle, 0);

        // Set the position of the camera on the x-z plane to:
        // distance meters behind the target
        transform.position = target.position;
        transform.position -= currentRotation * Vector3.forward * distance;

        // Set the height of the camera
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, currentHeight, transform.position.z);

        // Always look at the target
        transform.LookAt(target);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? How does it not work, are there any errors, what exactly are you expecting to happen when you do perform what action?

Comment: This camera looks at my player car, when i drag on screen left and right it also rotates, but I also want it to rotate vertically (up and down).

Comment: @Naeem look into the second parameter of the `LookAt` function, it controls the up vector.

Comment: Thank you. I just did it. Its working fine now.